# How to write RDD[String] to parquet file with schema inference?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-spark-sql

My `Spark Streaming` job needs to handle a `RDD[String]` where String corresponds to a row of a `csv` file. I don't know the schema beforehand so **I need to infer the schema** from the RDD then write its content to a `parquet` file. If I was reading a `csv` file from disk, I could just load everything into a `DataFrame` with schema inference and write it to parquet straight away. In my scenario though, my starting point is a `RDD[String]` that I get as a result of a stream.

Comment: What would you expect if the schema changes between rows?

Comment: Also, if the schema is not known, what kind of column structure do you expect on parquet? Could you illustrate with an example?

Answer (score 3):

It could be possible to do this in Spark 1.6.x, as the [csv library](https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv) from Databricks supports a method to transform a `RDD[String]` using the csv parser. In Spark version >= 2.0  this support has been merged onto the main project, and this method was removed from the interface. Also many of the methods are private, so it's harder to get around, but maybe it's worth exploring the underlying [univocity parsing library](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers)

Using Databricks' Spark CSV support on Spark 1.6.1, we can do something like this:

```
import com.databricks.spark.csv.CsvParser

val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sparkContext)
val parser = new CsvParser().withInferSchema(true)

val rdd = sparkContext.textFile("/home/maasg/playground/data/sample-no-header.csv")
rdd.take(1) // show a sample data 
// Array[String] = Array(2000,JOHN,KINGS,50)

val df = parser.csvRdd(sqlContext, rdd)
df.schema() // let's inspect the inferred schema
// org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(C0,IntegerType,true), StructField(C1,StringType,true), StructField(C2,StringType,true), StructField(C3,IntegerType,true))
df.write.parquet("/tmp/sample.parquet") // write it to parquet
```

It should be trivial to integrate such code in Spark Streaming, within a `foreachRDD{rdd => ...}` call.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your `RDD[String]` to `RDD[Row]` then you can pass the schema to convert `RDD[Row]` to `DataFrame`.

Please refer this.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#programmatically-specifying-the-schema

Comment: Thank you but I don't know the schema beforehand, as I wrote I need to infer the schema as I could do by reading a file from disk. I will make it even clearer in my question.

Comment: @AndreaT.Bonanno : Even if you have to read CSV file , you need to pass the column names as the first line of the CSV file, then only Spark can convert that as DF.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `RDD[String]`, you should also have a schema for the same in string format (or in any form - that you can parse)

So, for now,

```
// If we just thing of TWO FIELDS
val schema = "f1;f2"

// Generate the schema based on the string of schema
val f = schema.split(";").map(fn => StructField(fn, StringType))
val schema = StructType(f)

// Convert records of the RDD[String] to Rows
// Assuming each row in CSV have -comma- as delimiter
val rowRDD = <rdd>.map(_.split(",")).map(array => Row(array(0), array(1)))

// Apply the schema to the RDD
val df = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema)
```

You can now use `df` instance to save it to parquet format.

Comment: When you consume via Spark Streaming, you wont be getting the schema or column names as one of the row.

Comment: So, you should have schema by some means; or at-least, if you know no. of columns for each row, you can define your own column-names like `col1;col2;col3`.

But, end line is: you should know what you are receiving.

Or write a program first to parse few rows from RDD[String] - to identify column-names at beginning; and then converet it to DATAFRAME by applying that schema.

Comment: Even, databrick's open-csv lib needs column-names in case youo read from csv (first row); 

In your case, provide schema as `str1;str2;str3`; (by getting the no. of columns from the RDD)

Else, write your own program (perhaps - Machine-learning) to define column names.